# Not receiving input from user for 3x3 sliding tile slide

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to create a 3x3 sliding tile puzzle game and I made the puzzle in a 2d array and now im trying to get the puzzle to slide a tile.

I'm new to debugging and cannot find out why the program isn't receiving the users input for the slide.

```
#define SLIDE_UP        1       
#define SLIDE_DOWN      2       
#define SLIDE_LEFT      3       
#define SLIDE_RIGHT     4    

void InitializeBoard(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]);
void PrintBoard(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]);
bool slideTile(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int);
void scrambleBoard(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]);        
bool isBoardSolved(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]);
void DeallocateMemory(int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]);                                                 
int** ppRootPointer = NULL;

int main() {

int slidingBoard[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];       
char keyStroke = ' ';                        
int directionCode = UNSET;  
int slideDirection = 0;

InitializeBoard(slidingBoard);
PrintBoard(slidingBoard);
slideTile(slidingBoard,slideDirection);
PrintBoard(slidingBoard);

_getch();                                       
DeallocateMemory(slidingBoard);

return 0;
}

void InitializeBoard(int theBoard[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]) {

ppRootPointer = new(int*[NUM_COLS]);

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
    ppRootPointer[i] = new(int[NUM_ROWS]);
}

int counter = 1;
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
        ppRootPointer[i][j] = counter++;
    }
}
ppRootPointer[i-1][j-1] = PIVOT;


}

void PrintBoard(int theBoard[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]) {
    cout << left;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
            if (ppRootPointer[i][j] != PIVOT) {
                cout << setw(3) << ppRootPointer[i][j];
            }
            else {
                cout << setw(3) << (char)PIVOT;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

 bool slideTile(int theBoard[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int slideDirection) {
    int pivotRow=0;
    int pivotCol=0;
    bool slidebool;
    //once I declare i and j before the loop they go up to 3 instead of 2 
    //which causes the loop to not work
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {

            if (theBoard[i][j] == (char)PIVOT) {
                pivotCol = i;
                pivotRow = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //These are to assign pivotRow and Col because they dont get assigned 
    //inside of the loop
pivotCol = i;
pivotRow = j;

    cout << "please enter a number to slide the tile (1 = up, 2 = down, 3 = 
left, 4 = right" << endl;
    cin >> slideDirection;

    if (slideDirection == SLIDE_UP) {
        if (pivotRow + 1 > NUM_ROWS) {
            slidebool = false;
        }
        else {
            ppRootPointer[pivotRow + 1][pivotCol] = PIVOT;
            ppRootPointer[pivotRow][pivotCol] = ppRootPointer[pivotRow + 1] 
[pivotCol];
            slidebool = true;

        }
    }
```

.I'm hoping for the user to be able to enter an integer 1-4 representing the slide for the tile. This would allow me to build the scramble board function and get closer to finishing the code. Thanks to anyone that reads this and tries to help!!

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the feedback man! I just put in a small sliver of the code showing the beginning of the function and one of the slide tiles.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and then run the program. Force a slide, however you do it. Check the value of `slideDirection` to make sure it is what you expect. If it's correct, step through the function to see where the program does something you don't expect. That's probably the bug. If  `slideDirection` isn't what you expect it to be, the problem is elsewhere. If the breakpoint never triggers, this function is never called and the problem must be elsewhere. It's because of the "problem is elsewhere" cases that we'd like to see a [mcve]...

Comment: but the true beauty of the MCVE is as you construct one, you almost always find and fix the bug yourself.

Comment: I've been debugging to try to find out the problem and it seems to be the for loop to find the pivot (the empty tile). After I exit the for loop pivotRow and pivotCol are both 0 even though they should be 2 and 2. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Can you prove they were ever set? Step through the loop with the debugger and see what happens.

Comment: @user4581301 well I was debugging and i and j would move through the loop and be 2 but then once it was ended pivotRow and pivotCol weren't set and I added the same code I have in the loop to set the variables outside right after and they were both set as 3.

Comment: @user4581301 I also tried declaring the variables i and j before the loop but that is what caused them to for some reason go up to 3. So I commented those out and tried running it but then it said that they were undeclared because they were then only declared inside of the loop which I understand.

Comment: I'm not seeing that unless you have multiple pivots on the board. Could we have a [mcve]?

Comment: @user4581301 i dont really know what that is I read it and it's alot of code to try to get all of it to fit and be formatted but I could just put what ive added. edit: I edited the post to show what I currently have.

Comment: You're missing the goal of MCVE. Please read the link.

Comment: @user4581301 I read the link and i tried to add as much code to make it be able to run. So I only added in the ability to slide the tile up. Hopefully this is sort of how you wanted the MCVE to be but probably not lol. Also Sorry for the formatting should I start to use 4 spaces in my ide instead of pressing tab?

Comment: [This is my idea of an MCVE](https://ideone.com/cfA2uB). A small program that exercises ONLY the part of the code that's causing problems. Everything else is gone. It duplicates the error with practically no code so that it is easier to see the cause of the problem. The break is a good idea. Unfortunately it only breaks out of one of the two loops, so the  outer loop keeps spinning and ruins `i` and `j`. https://ideone.com/gwdzO5 gets it mostly right. https://ideone.com/8MjoCr uses a function to return from both loops to save some scanning time.

Comment: The code does not compile, ... MCVE's compile :-).